# I need help declaring variables

Tags: java

I'm very new at Java, and I'm not sure how to declare variables in my code. I have to declare init1 with J., init2 with M., and init3 with F. (With the periods.)

I've tried doing what I did with numbers, int. So far I've only worked with numbers. This code is what I have so far.

```
class Initials {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int init1;
        int init2;
        int init3;
        init1 = J;
        init2 = M;
        init3 = F;
        System.out.println("Here are your initials " + init1 + init2 + init3);
    }
}
```

I expect the output to display J.M.F. using the declared variables.

Comment: The variables are declared as `int`.  Are you looking for some numeric value for "J", such as a byte or ASCII code or something?  Or should the variables be a `String`, or `char`?  Something else?  Please clarify the intent here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java when you declare a variable you need to declare its `type`.

In your case, you are declaring your variables as `int`, which means you want to put a *whole number* into it.  For example, you can do `int value = 5;`.

Now if you want to store a single *character* you can use the type `char` and use single quotes around the value.  This would look like `char value = 'J';`.

A third important type to learn is `String`.  This will allow you store *multiple* characters in a row, but you need double quotes for the value.  This will look like this `String value = "J.M.F.";`.

For your scenario, it would make sense to create a single variable as a `String` and display the values together.  Optionally you could also store each individual character as `char` and display them together in the `print`, though this is not recommended unless necessary.

Before you were attempting to cram *letters* into a field that only takes *whole numbers*!

The improved code using `String` would look like this below:

```
class Initials {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String initials = "J.M.F.";
        System.out.println("Here are your initials: " + initials);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Here are your initials: J.M.F.

**Note:**  There are many other types I have not included here, and you can even make your own types!  This is mainly a guide to some of the basic ones you will see.  A few of the other types include `boolean`, `double`, and `long`.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for more details from the documentation on some different types.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Initials {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String init1 = "J.";
        String init2 = "M.";
        String init3 = "F.";
        System.out.println("Here are your initials " + init1 + init2 + init3);
    }
}
```

You have several options as Java provides many types. The code example above is using the String type, which allows for storing multiple characters. So the initial along with the period can be stored together. Also, one convenient way that String objects can be concatenated is using the "+" operator.

Comment: Please provide an explanation along with code in an answer. Code without an explanation as to what the code does and why it works and why the code is an answer to the question posted is a poor quality answer.

Comment: I added comments to improved the answer as suggested. Thanks Richard.

Answer (score -1):

Use type `char` for letters, not type `int` (which is for integers, or numbers).

Put literal Character values in quotes, otherwise, Java thinks you are referring to variables named `J`, `M` and `F`.

```
class Initials {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char init1;   // char is for letters, int is for Integer/Numbers
        char init2;
        char init3;
        init1 = 'J';  // Single-quote for Literal character values
        init2 = 'M';
        init3 = 'F';
        System.out.println("Here are your initials " + init1 + init2 + init3);
    }
}
```

[IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/IVAFZU) proving it works.

### Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0.12s 36572KB
Here are your initials JMF
```

---

If you want the period after each one, then use Strings (which are more than one character):

```
class Initials {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String init1;   // String is for a sequence of letters
        String init2;
        String init3;
        init1 = "J.";  // DoubleQuotes Literal String Values
        init2 = "M.";
        init3 = "F.";
        System.out.println("Here are your initials " + init1 + init2 + init3);
    }
}
```

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0.12s 37092KB
Here are your initials J.M.F.
```